# MacBook Air M1 2020 touchpad and keyboard unresponsive after sleep

Tags: macos, sleep-wake, apple-silicon

For the last week, I've been experiencing the following issue: After my MacBook Air (M1, 2020, Monterey 12.6.3 (21G419)) goes to sleep, it becomes unresponsive to touch and keyboard; only the power button works (and signing in successfully, hence I could physically screenshot the console error logs below.)

Any help and pointers would be much appreciated since I am travelling currently and need the machine.

I have already tried:

- Booting in safe mode (issue persists)
- Full reinstall after wiping SSD clean (issue persists)

The following kernel error messages show up in console:

```
Sandbox: swed (464) deny (1) system-fsctl _IO('h',
47)
[HID] (0x100000787][41c][AppleHIDTransportProtocolHIDSPI::powerHasChanged]:ERROR!/ioRet == 0
file: /AppleInternal/Library/BuildRoots/f1d94df-906-11ed-8745-66a073a27ee/Library/Cac[...]
[HID] (0x1000004ea][41c][AppleHIDTransportDeviceSPI::interruptAction]: ERROR!I boolResult,
file: /AppleInternal/Library/BuildRoots/f1d9e4df-906-11ed-8745-66a073a27ee/Library/Caches/cc
[HID] [®x1000004ea][41c][AppleHIDTransportDeviceSPI::handleFatalError]: ERRORI! Couldn't talk to firmware
[HID] (8x1000004ea][41c][AppleHIDTransportDeviceSPI::handleFatalError]: ERRORI/ Powering off due to reaching maximum number of consecutive boot failures (10
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This appears to be a hardware issue**.

The one error message that stands out is:

```
ERRORI! Couldn't talk to firmware
```

When a process cannot speak to the firmware (on your logic board) especially after a clean reinstall of the OS, this is not something that a tweak of a setting in the OS will fix.

This is hardware related and your Mac needs to go in for service.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem comes from update new macOS 13.x.x I had met the same issue with all 2 my macbook air m1 - 2020. Maybe reinstall macos can work! In my case, I try to reinstall to stock MacOS